# Solve the tower equation: $\displaystyle x^{x^{x^{x+1}+x+1}}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, contest-math, exponential-function, power-towers

> We are struggling to solve a crazy looking equation below:
> $$\displaystyle x^{x^{x^{x+1}+x+1}}=2$$

Approximate numerical values ​​are unfortunately not a solution. Wolfram Alpha offers only the following approximate solution:

$$x\approx 1.28486974908322\dots$$

A quote from the author: " The equation can be solved mathematically " .

This equation is not a homework and it seems hard to solve.  At least it seems that way to me.  However, I know the solution of an equation similar to this equation .

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}=2$$

So, we have

$$x^2=2$$

which implies $x=\sqrt {2}$ .

**My opinion**

Probably $x$ is an algebraic number. For example, $x=\sqrt {\frac {3}{2}}$.  However, it is difficult to find.

**My questions**

Do you think we can establish a similarity between the solutions of these equations?

Wolfram Alpha cannot solve the equation for the exact value of $x$ . Can other computer software solve the equation?

Comment: Numerical Solution : $x=1.28486857142857$ gives output $1.99998789347940$ while $x=1.28487142857142$ gives output $2.00001726575946$

Comment: How is `\displaystyle` allowed in the title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we need to denote the solution to the following basic equation $$t^t=2\Longrightarrow t=e^{W(\ln2)}\tag{1}$$

where $W$ is Lambert-W function, and you can find [here.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) Now, we are ready to solve it.
$$L=x^{x^{x^{x+1}+x+1}}=\left(x\right)^{x\cdot x^x\cdot x^{x^{x+1}}}=\left(x^x\right)^{x^x\cdot x^{x^{x+1}}}$$

Let $x^x=y$

$$L=\left(y\right)^{y\cdot x^{y\cdot x}}=y^{y\cdot (x^{x})^y}=y^{y\cdot y^y}$$

Let $t=y^y$

$$L=t^t=2$$

Now, use (1), we get

$$\boxed{x=e^{W(W(W(\ln2)))}}$$

[Numericall verify](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5Elambert%20w%20function%28lambert%20w%20function%28lambert%20w%20function%28ln2%29%29%29):
[image]


and


[image]

Comment: Since "can be solved mathematically" doesn't have a clear definition, this answer should be the best to expect.